# AMP button vs div behavior

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to attach a tap event to a div. I have the following snippet.

```
<div class="scroller" on="tap:description.scrollTo(duration=500, position=top)">
  <svg id="svg-icon-scroller" width="574px" height="574px" viewBox="0 0 574 574" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="242.230044 0 344.159764 0 344.159764 342.046041 495.160004 342.046041 292.832713 573.99967 79 342.452068 242.374538 342.452068"></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

this snippet gives me the error

```
The parent tag of tag 'FORM > DIV [submit-success]' is 'body', but it can only be 'form'.
```

According to the documentation, the tap event can be used on any element. Also when I switch the snippet to

```
<button class="scroller" on="tap:description.scrollTo(duration=500, position=top)">
  <svg id="svg-icon-scroller" width="574px" height="574px" viewBox="0 0 574 574" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="242.230044 0 344.159764 0 344.159764 342.046041 495.160004 342.046041 292.832713 573.99967 79 342.452068 242.374538 342.452068"></polygon>
  </svg>
</button>
```

I don't receive the error. How do I properly attach the event to the div element?

Answer (score 1):

This `<div id="description"></div>` is missing on the top, place it just after `<body>` tag, for top position.

[image]